Is the following constraint a second-order cone constraint?
We all know that the following constraint is called second-order cone constraint
$$
\|Ax + b\|_2 \leq c^T x + d
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{(k-1) \times n}$, $b \in \mathbb{R}^{k-1}$, $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $d \in \mathbb{R}$.
What if the left-hand side expression breaks into pieces in the folloing form
$$
\|A_1 x_1 + b\|_2 + \cdots + \|A_i x_i + b\|_2 + \cdots + \|A_I x_I + b\|_2 \leq c^T x + d
$$
where $x$ is separated into $I$ small vectors $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{I}$.
Will the consequent constraint still be a convex constraint?

It is a sum of convex functions, hence convex: $t\geq \sum_i f_i(x)$ is the same as $t= \sum_i y_i$ plus $y_i\geq f_i(x)$ for all $i$.

@MichalAdamaszek, it would be great if you could convert your comment into an answer. :)

@MichalAdamaszek Thank you for answering. I think you're right.
